# fullcalendar "typeError: Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, fullcalendar

My jQuery Full Calendar was working fine until I added some events. I am now getting the error: fullcalendar  "typeError: Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined" I think this is referring to range (JS lines in fullcal.js have to do with range normalization.(  When I console.log(range) I get [object Object] .   I have a start time, have added an end time and tried setting allday to true but its not working.

see https://github.com/Brigette-Eckert/PacNW-Race-Calendar for repository.
[Screenshot of page with console open to see errror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hhEC.png)

Comment: Are you including [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

Brigette,

This is because I could see a junk data "uglyHolidaySweaterRun15"(string) in between your event objects (raceJSON.js).

You can make it work once you remove that.