# Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, fullcalendar, laravel-5.1

I'm using FullCalendar to display staff hours on a Calendar.

I'm pulling the events via an ajax call like so:

```
"events": function(start, end, timezone, callback) {

  //create the data to be sent
  var objectToSend = {
    "start_date": start.format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
    "finish_date": end.format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
  };

  //craft and make the request
  $.ajax({
    url: 'calendar/test',
    data: objectToSend,
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false
  }).done(function(data) {
    //on success call `callback` with the data
    callback(data)
  })
}
```

This works perfectly fine, however I am getting an error showing in my console "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined" and that this is coming from `fullcalendar.min.js:6`.

I'm not very fluent in JavaScript, but my searching suggests that I either haven't provided the [right dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28027748/fullcalendar-v-2-2-6-hastime-undefined-error-when-using-addeventsource) or have [junk data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33989648/fullcalendar-typeerror-cannot-read-property-hastime-of-undefined) in there.

As far as I can tell I am providing all the right data. The function generating the data looks like so:

```
public function test(Request $request) {
  $start_date = Input::get('start_date');
  $finish_date = Input::get('finish_date');

  $shifts = Roster::whereBetween('date', array($start_date, $finish_date)) - > get();

  foreach($shifts as $shift) {
    $start = $shift - > date.
    ' '.$shift - > start_time;
    $finish = $shift - > date.
    ' '.$shift - > finish_time;

    $events[] = array(
      'title' => $shift - > staff - > first_name,
      'start' => Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start) - > toDateTimeString(),
      'end' => Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $finish) - > toDateTimeString(),
      'id' => $shift - > id,
      'allDay' => false
    );
  }

  return json_encode($events);
}
```

which outputs:

```
[{"title":"Gemma","start":"2016-02-01 18:00:00","end":"2016-02-01 22:00:00","id":1,"allDay":false},
{"title":"Gemma","start":"2016-01-26 18:00:00","end":"2016-01-26 22:00:00","id":49,"allDay":false}]
```

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong? I am simply trying to use this to render my events for the given month.

**Edit: output of console.log(data)**

It prints out:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

Opening this up I get:

`0: Object`

Opening this up I get:

```
allDay: false
end: "2016-02-01 22:00:00"
id: 1
start: "2016-02-01 18:00:00"
title: "Gemma"
```

Comment: show  `callback` function ..

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko I'm just trying to follow this http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/ not sure where the callback function is? Except rather than provide the response as XML, I am providing it as JSON.

Comment: ok, try to replace `callback(data)` to `callback(data[0])`

Comment: could you  provide console.log(data) before calling callback in `done` funciton

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko Just tried that, I get the same error.

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko output of `console.log(data)` added. There are more objects there as I only provided two in my example output.

Comment: Try to change date format: currently your start and end is  `"2016-02-01 18:00:00"` format  it in next way `"2016-02-01T18:00:00"` (add `T` before hours), that's could cause failure while building date in `callback` method

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko It shouldn't need the T as I can build the events just fine without it. For example, if I manually build the events with the example output, which is the same as what I get from each object, it works. However, I will try adding the T shortly

Comment: ok, what's about replacing `done` callback to `success` also, you could define `success` property as in examples on fullCalendar official page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't figure out what was going wrong with the above code, however I got around it by using a JSON feed instead:

```
events: {
            url: 'calendar/test',
            error: function() 
            {
                alert("error");
            },
            success: function()
            {
                console.log("successfully loaded");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be you are giving to `fullCalendar` wrong event's parameter,

Try to render some manually events first.

```
events: [{
  title: 'event1',
  start: '2010-01-01'
}, {
  title: 'event2',
  start: '2010-01-05',
  end: '2010-01-07'
}, {
  title: 'event3',
  start: '2010-01-09T12:30:00',
  allDay: false // will make the time show
}]
```

After that, make sure your events match with fullCalendar expected params.

Comment: I was rendering them successfully before manually, it was when I implemented this that I started getting trouble.

Comment: Also providing the output manually works just fine, i.e `[{"title":"Gemma","start":"2016-02-01 18:00:00","end":"2016-02-01 22:00:00","id":1,"allDay":false}]` shows the event successfully.

Comment: Make sure json_encode is giving to you json a right format.

Try to check with jQuery.parseJSON(), for some reason the fullCalendar doesn't like your data format in start param or end.

Comment: How do I use `jQuery.parseJSON()`?

Comment: In my personal case I parse the event's response using the moment.js library manually.
Making something like this:
events = [];
events.push( {
     id: events.id,
     title: events.title,
     start: moment(events.startDate).toDate(),
     end: moment(events.endDate).toDate(),
     description: events.description,
     allDay: events.allDay
    } );

and returning the event array, this way you make sure that dates are correctly parsed. But you can use JavaScript Date() function too.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to do this with an ajax call to fetch the dates based on the month?

Comment: With your output : 
`[{"title":"Gemma","start":"2016-02-01 18:00:00","end":"2016-02-01 22:00:00","id":1,"allDay":false},
{"title":"Gemma","start":"2016-01-26 18:00:00","end":"2016-01-26 22:00:00","id":49,"allDay":false}];`

`fullCalendar` should be able to parse your events, make sure your `callback()` function is defined and return `JSON.parse(data)` instead of `data`.

Answer (score 0):

I got this bug, with the following function

```
var postToServerAjax = function(event, delta, revertFunc)
    {
      $.post('/url', {event: event}, function(data)
      {

      }, 'json').fail(function()
      {
        revertFunc();
        alert('We got an error.');
      });
    };
```

And I found it was because I tried to pass the event on to the post() function. It didn't matter if I changed the name, as soon as I passed it along, I think it tried to serialize it, and it resulted in that error. Now I'm manually specifying and object, where I "clone" the relevant id, start and end over, as I don't need anything else anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use: `JSON.parse(data)` in reponse ajax.